# Как вызвать функцию дочернего класса из вектора базового класса?

Tags: c++, классы

Есть базовый класс Matrix, есть также подкласс SQUARE_MATRIX. В main есть вектор указателей на Matrix. Так как вызвать функцию из SQUARE_MATRIX? class "Matrix" не содержит члена "FIND_MAX_MIN_DIAGONAL"   Matrix. Выдаёт такую ошибку.

```
class Matrix {
protected:
    int COLUMNS, ROWS;
    int MAX, MIN;

    vector<int> MAX_IN_COLUMN; // MAX ELEMENT IN ALL COLUMN
    vector<int> MIN_IN_COLUMN; // MIN ELEMENT IN ALL COLUMN

    vector<int> MAX_IN_ROW; // MAX ELEMENT IN ALL ROWS
    vector<int> MIN_IN_ROW; // MIN ELEMENT IN ALL ROWS

    vector<vector<int>> MATRX; // MATRIX
public:
    Matrix(int clm = 0, int row = 0) {
        COLUMNS = clm;
        ROWS = row;

        MATRX.assign(clm, vector<int>(row));

        MAX = 0;
        MIN = 0;
    }
    
    friend void MATRIX_ADDITION_DB(vector<shared_ptr<Matrix>> &matrx, int); /// ADDITON MATRIX FROM DATABASE
    friend void MATRIX_SUBTRACTION_DB(vector<shared_ptr<Matrix>> &matrx, int); /// SUBTRACTION MATRIX FROM DATABASE 
    friend void MATRIX_MULTIPLICATION_DB(vector<shared_ptr<Matrix>> &matrx, int); /// MULTIPLICATION MATRIX FROM DATABASE
    friend void MATRIX_SORT(vector<shared_ptr<Matrix>> &matrx, int); /// SORT MATRIX
    void FIND_MAX();
    void FIND_MIN();
    void FIND_MAX_AND_MIN_IN_ALL_COLUMN();
    void FIND_MAX_AND_MIN_IN_ALL_ROW();

    void FILL_RANDOM_MATRIX(int, int);
    void FILL_MATRIX();
    void SHOW_MATRX();
    void SHOW_MAX_MIN();

    //void setColumns(int clm) { COLUMNS = clm; } // SET COLUMNS
    int getColumns() { return COLUMNS; } // GET COLUMNS

    //void setRows(int rows) { ROWS = rows; } // SET ROWS
    int getRows() { return ROWS; } // GET ROWS
    int getMax() { return MAX; } // GET MAX
    int getMin() { return MIN; } // GET MIN*/
};

//// SQUARE_MATRIX CLASS /////////
class SQUARE_MATRIX : virtual public Matrix {
private:
    int MAX_IN_MAIN_DG; // MAX IN MAIN DIAGONAL
    int MIN_IN_MAIN_DG; // MIN IN MAIN DIAGONAL

    int MAX_IN_NMAIN_DG; // MAX IN NOT MAIN DIAGONAL
    int MIN_IN_NMAIN_DG; // MIN IN NOT MAIN DIAGONAL


public:
    SQUARE_MATRIX(int m) : Matrix(m, m) {
        MAX_IN_MAIN_DG = 0; // MAX IN MAIN DIAGONAL
        MIN_IN_MAIN_DG = 0; // MIN IN MAIN DIAGONAL

        MAX_IN_NMAIN_DG = 0; // MAX IN NOT MAIN DIAGONAL
        MIN_IN_NMAIN_DG = 0; // MIN IN NOT MAIN DIAGONAL
    }

    void FIND_MAX_MIN_DIAGONAL();

    int getMAX_IN_MAIN_DG() { return MAX_IN_MAIN_DG; } // GET MAX IN MAIN DIAGONAL
    int getMIN_IN_MAIN_DG() { return MIN_IN_MAIN_DG; } // GET MIN IN MAIN DIAGONAL

    int getMAX_IN_NMAIN_DG() { return MAX_IN_NMAIN_DG; } // GET MAX IN NOT MAIN DIAGONAL
    int getMIN_IN_NMAIN_DG() { return MIN_IN_NMAIN_DG; } // GET MIN IN NOT MAIN DIAGONAL
};

int main() {
   vector<shared_ptr<Matrix>> matrx;
   matrx.push_back(make_shared<SQUARE_MATRIX>(5));
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::static_pointer_cast<SQUARE_MATRIX>(matrx[0])->FIND_MAX_MIN_DIAGONAL();
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы точно уверены, что `matrx[0]` указывает на объект `SQARE_MATRIX`, тогда используйте `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<SQUARE_MATRIX &>(*matrx[0]).FIND_MAX_MIN_DIAGONAL();
```

Если не уверены, и при этом `Matrix` *полиморфный* (содержит хотя бы одну виртуальную функцию), тогда можно использовать `dynamic_cast`. Если не угадаете тип, получите исключение:

```
dynamic_cast<SQUARE_MATRIX &>(*matrx[0]).FIND_MAX_MIN_DIAGONAL();
```

Comment: Зря я вроде взялся за такую сложную штуку пока что)) Я пока не разбираюсь хорошо в классах а виртуальные функции вообще не знаю)). Я код немножко изменил и если там можно что то исправить исправлю если нет перепишу тогда)